# How to dockerize Ruby on Rails for production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, docker, unicorn, puma

I set up Ruby on Rails with docker for my development environment and I am not sure if this configuration is also fine for production. Currently I use nginx + unicorn as webserver but what about nginx + passenger  or nginx + puma?

I show you my docker setup and hopefully you have some improvements.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
web:
  image: nginx:latest
  ports:
    - "80"
    - "443"
  links:
    - "rails"
  environment:
    VIRTUAL_HOST: blog.dev.lvh
  volumes:
    - ./log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
    - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    - ./docker/nginx/sites-enabled:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled
    - ./docker/nginx/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
  volumes_from:
    - rails

rails:
  image: mc388/rails:latest
  environment:
    RACK_ENV: development
    RAILS_ENV: development
  command: bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb
  volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/html
  links:
    - mysql

mysql:
  image: mysql:latest
  volumes:
    - ./mysql/dev:/var/lib/mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somepw
    MYSQL_DATABASE: mablen_dev
```

**nginx.conf**

```
user                    nginx;
worker_processes        1;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
    #default_type        text/html;

    log_format          main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                              '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                              '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log          /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    error_log           /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

    sendfile            on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;

    include             /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**sites-endable/rails.conf**

```
upstream app {
    # Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/var/www/html/unicorn/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen                      80 default_server;
    listen                      443 default_server ssl;

    ssl_certificate             /etc/nginx/ssl/blog.dev.io.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key         /etc/nginx/ssl/blog.dev.io.key;

    # Application root, as defined previously
    root                        /var/www/html/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;

    include                     /etc/nginx/includes/gzip;


    # For Lets Encrypt
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
      root /var/www/html;
      default_type application/jose+json;
    }
}
```

**config/unicorn.rb**

```
# set path to application
app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
shared_dir = "#{app_dir}/unicorn"
working_directory app_dir

# Set unicorn options
worker_processes 2
preload_app true
timeout 30

before_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end

# Set up socket location
listen "#{shared_dir}/sockets/unicorn.sock", :backlog => 64

# Logging
stderr_path "#{shared_dir}/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "#{shared_dir}/log/unicorn.stdout.log"

# Set master PID location
pid "#{shared_dir}/pids/unicorn.pid"
```